# Oracle SQL Developer - Export only constraints

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to export only constraints with SQL Developer from a table. I right clicked on table that I am interested and clicked on export, but I did not see any option to just export constraints. Wanted to check with the forum, if I am missing something. The version of SQL Developer I am using is 3.2.20.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Hope it helps someone. You can click on the table and then on the right pane click on constraints tab. This will list all the constraints. You can then right click on the list and say export.

Comment: In Edit Table panel, You can use DDL section.